# How to access data pulled in ViewControllerA in another ViewControllerB?

Tags: ios, json, swift, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller

What should be the best possible way to get the data from ViewControllerA to ViewControllerB.

Here ViewContollerA has the data pulled from web by JSON parsing.
And ViewControllerB has the text view and labels that are to be filled by the data pulled in ViewControllerA

Any guide or reference would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?rq=1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44877352/passing-data-from-one-view-controller-to-another/44877517#44877517

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.

- pass data through segues
- notification center
- static object/service
- and more!

I found [how-ios-view-controllers-communicate-with-each-other](http://matteomanferdini.com/how-ios-view-controllers-communicate-with-each-other/) for you